# getting all daily oil prices from a dropdown menu in R

Tags: html, r, dataframe, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get oil prices in all counties of Istanbul from this link:

https://www.petrolofisi.com.tr/akaryakit-fiyatlari

which has two dropdown list for selection of cities and counties, with the following code:

```
IST_DATA  <- data.frame(Sehir ="ISTANBUL",Ilce="ADALAR")
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="AVCILAR"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="BAGCILAR"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="BAHCELIEVLER"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="BAKIRKOY"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="BAYRAMPASA"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="BESIKTAS"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="BEYKOZ"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="BEYOGLU"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="BUYUKCEKMECE"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="CATALCA"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="EMINONU"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="ESENLER"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="EYUP"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="FATIH"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="GAZIOSMANPASA"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="GUNGOREN"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="ISTANBUL_ANA"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="ISTANBUL_TRA"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="KADIKOY"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="KAGITHANE"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="KARTAL"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="KUCUKCEKMECE"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="MALTEPE"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="PENDIK"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="SARIYER"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="SILE"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="SILIVRI"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="SISLI"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="SULTANBEYLI"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="TUZLA"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="UMRANIYE"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="USKUDAR"))
IST_DATA  <- rbind.data.frame(IST_DATA,  data.frame(Sehir="ISTANBUL", Ilce="ZEYTINBURNU"))

FileData <- as.data.frame(NULL)

for(i in 1:nrow(IST_DATA))
{ 
 url <- sprintf("https://www.petrolofisi.com.tr/posvc/fiyat/guncel?il=%s&Ilce=%s", IST_DATA$Sehir[i], IST_DATA$Ilce[i])
 download.file(url,"petrolofisi.html", quiet=TRUE)
 AppendData <- as.data.frame(read_html("petrolofisi.html") %>% html_text(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)     
 FileData <- rbind.data.frame(FileData,AppendData)
 rownames(FileData)[i] <- as.character(IST_DATA$Ilce[i])
}
View(FileData)
write_excel_csv2( x= FileData, path="AKARYAKIT.xls")
```

and this resulted in a not-so-desired output like:

[image: Oil Prices]

`rownames` did not show up in excel and data is not seperated into cells. How can I write this code more efficient so that:

1. I may not need to specify all counties in `IST_DATA`.
2. Get data exactly as a table as seen in web page.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)
if(curl::has_internet()==TRUE) {
  link="https://www.petrolofisi.com.tr/posvc/fiyat/ililce?il=ISTANBUL"
  r <- GET(link)
  city=fromJSON(content(r,"text"))
  
  data_all <- data.frame()
  for(i in city$Ilceler) {
    link=paste0("https://www.petrolofisi.com.tr/posvc/fiyat/guncel?il=ISTANBUL&Ilce=",i)
    r <- GET(link)
    res=fromJSON(content(r,"text"))
    paste(res)
    data_all <- bind_rows(data_all, res)
           }
  
  table_oil = data_all %>% mutate(counties=city$Ilceler,V_Max_Lead_Free_95=as.double(K95),V_Max_Lead_Free_97=as.double(K97),V_Max_EuroDiesel=as.double(Mot50),V_Pro_EuroDiesel=as.double(MotPro),PO_gas=as.double(PoGaz)) %>% select(AktarimTarihi,counties,V_Max_Lead_Free_95,V_Max_Lead_Free_97,V_Max_EuroDiesel,V_Pro_EuroDiesel,PO_gas)
  write.xlsx(table_oil, 'table_oil.xlsx')
 } else { print("check your internet connection is working properly") }
```

[image]

Comment: When internet is down I naturally get error ' "Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Could not resolve host: www.petrolofisi.com.tr". Could you please suggest me a snippet for handling this error ? I only need to output my own error mesage, many thanks.

Comment: This error is due to fail to connect with the host and also please make sure the packages are installed correctly.

Comment: I think I could not explain. I need to run this program through a Unix shell, so when my customer's internet is down he needs to know this. I will display an error message "check your internet connection is working properly" when I encounter 'Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Could not resolve host: www.petrolofisi.com.tr'

Comment: I have updated the code, now the code will check for the internet connection then only it fetches the oil price from the URL. used curl::has_internet()==TRUE to check the connection